# Using log4net to write to two different files

Tags: c#, log4net

I want to use two different loggers in my app, so I will be able to log different messages into the different files.
My app.config looks like

```
<log4net>
<appender name="Appender1" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="File1" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <datePattern value=".yyyy-MM-dd'.txt'" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message %exception{Message} %newline" />
    <IgnoresException value="False" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="Appender2" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="File2.Log"/>
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %message %newline" />
    <IgnoresException value="True" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<logger Name="Logger1" additivity="false">
  <level value="INFO"/>
  <appender-ref ref="Appender1" />
</logger>
<logger Name="Logger2" additivity="false">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="Appender2" />
</logger>
```

Inside the class the loggers are initialized like:

```
private static readonly ILog Log1 = LogManager.GetLogger("Logger1");
private static readonly ILog Log2 = LogManager.GetLogger("Logger2");
```

And I write the messages:

```
Log1.Info("Message1");
Log2.Debug("Message1");
```

The log files are created but they are empty. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe try and activate [log4net's debugging messages](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug). At first glance, I don't see anything obvious.

Comment: @Fildor I've tried to activate debugging messages but still the same problem. During debugging I've noticed that the logger doesn't have assigned any appenders. See attached screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Works for me..You can tweak the Pattern the way you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net debug="false">

  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs/Abc.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="45" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] %line - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="All" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
  </root>

  <!--For Call BAck  Only-->
  <appender name="Summary" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs/Callback.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="45" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] %line - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger additivity="false" name="Summary">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Summary" />
  </logger>


  <!--One More Log-->
  <appender name="Quartz" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs/Quartz.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="45" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] %line - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger additivity="false" name="Quartz">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Quartz" />
  </logger>

</log4net>
```

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works for me. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to Help...!!

Answer (score 2):

I had two appenders and they were both recording every error multiple times.

The property I needed was in the accepted answer, `additivity`

```
  <logger additivity="false" name="Summary">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Summary" />
  </logger>
```

Now the errors go to the correct file and don't get recorded multiple times

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this param:

`<"param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />`

ImmediateFlush will flush the content each time the Write method is called.

Otherwise, you would have to call Flush yourself :)

Comment: "<param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />"

Comment: You can **edit** your answer by using the greyish "edit" link beneath it.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't show me the full XML element, it just empties the space :(

But I am new to StackOverflow as a member, was using it without any acc for few years :) not I want to give back to community :)

Comment: Which is great. In the editor, there is a "formatting help" link (the little questionmark in a circle to the right). For most situations you'll find your formatting solutions there.